# Local network for websites

Tags: ubuntu, local-area-network, vagrant

I'm a student doing an internship at the moment. I mainly develop websites using virtualbox and vagrant. I was wondering if i could like make the websites i build accessible for everyone in my network. What is the best way to do this. Im on a mac by the way.

Comment: What kind of issue are you trying to resolve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your firewall allows the local network to access your webserver port (80 most of the time) then they can access by IP address indeed.

And if you want them to be able to access it via a domain name, you can have them use their hosts file to make a DNS record matching this domain name to your IP address.

Depending on the networking setup, you may be able to achieve this domain routing on the company firewall/router.

Comment: This did the trick

Answer (score -1):

If people connect to your `IP` on a web browser, they will be able to see it.